# Running query without intermediate data creation in sql

Tags: sql

My query looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE work_pr.op1 AS

SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt
    ,org_sales_price
FROM md1.item_lv1_org_price_m
WHERE fr_cntry_cde = '01';

CREATE TABLE work_pr.op2 AS

SELECT level1_idnt
    ,org_sales_price
FROM work_pr.op1
WHERE org_sales_price IS NOT NULL;

CREATE TABLE work_pr.final_op AS

SELECT level1_idnt
    ,avg(org_sales_price) AS op
FROM work_pr.op2
GROUP BY level1_idnt;
```

I want the steps to be in same sequence except that I dont want to create work_pr.op1 and the work_pr.op2 tables. How can I shorten this process in sql. I am very new to sql and any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You don't need to create the tables, you can use common table expresions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use nested selects in order to create a single table, the last one:

```
CREATE TABLE work_pr.final_op AS

SELECT level1_idnt
    ,avg(org_sales_price) AS op
FROM (
    SELECT level1_idnt
        ,org_sales_price
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt
            ,org_sales_price
        FROM md1.item_lv1_org_price_m
        WHERE fr_cntry_cde = '01'
        ) result_set_1
    WHERE org_sales_price IS NOT NULL
    ) result_set_2
GROUP BY level1_idnt;
```

As @GordonLinoff mentioned, the `SELECT` can be simplified and you can use the one in his answer.

Comment: what is the role of rs1 and rs2?

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra All nested SELECT must have an ALIAS

Answer (score 1):

You can write the query as:

```
SELECT level1_idnt, AVG(org_sales_price) as op
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt, org_sales_price
      FROM md1.item_lv1_org_price_m
      WHERE fr_cntry_cde = '01' AND org_sales_price IS NOT NULL
     ) l
GROUP BY level1_idnt;
```

However, it should be unnecessary to have the `DISTINCT` in the subquery.  Normally, the query would be simplified to:

```
SELECT level1_idnt, AVG(org_sales_price) as op
FROM md1.item_lv1_org_price_m
WHERE fr_cntry_cde = '01' AND org_sales_price IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY level1_idnt;
```

Comment: I'm curious if the optimizer wouldn't actually avoid making the `DISTINCT` at the first level since you're doing a `GROUP BY` later on, if you were to use nested selects.

Comment: You are right. The simplified query yields the same result

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra . . . I'm surprised you accepted the more complex answer.  The OP can accept whichever answer s/he wants to -- and for whatever reason.  It just surprises me in this case.

Comment: Actually I had accepted it before your answer as it worked. But I can acknowledge that your solution is more simple and elegant

Comment: Actually, I believe the OP's problem was how to avoid creating additional and temporary tables only to get intermediate result sets (`"shorten the process"`). My answer did not provide the best approach (in terms of "short" and "elegant"), but it offered a full solution and was very similar to what OP already posted. I acknowledge that the `SELECT` can be simplified as you have done and since you were faster than me at doing this I +1 ed your answer and did not add the same `SELECT` myself since I wouldn't want to be later accused of `"copy-pasting"`.